# Linking static libraries into shared: enum class in header -> relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, shared-libraries, static-linking

**What I want to do**

I try to separate my code into modules, which are compiled as static libraries with the `-fPIC` option.

Finally, they are to be linked into a shared library using `--whole-archive`, also compiled with `-fPIC`.

For the whole compilation, I use `CMake generated make files` and `C++17` with `GCC8`!

[image]

**Problem**

Trying to do so with `GCC8 x86_64` and `libstdc++_pic` fails with:

> /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: CMakeFiles/shirabeengine.dir/code/source/core/engine.cpp.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `_ZN6enginelsERSoRKNS_13EEngineStatusE' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>   /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: final link failed: Bad value
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

---

**Performed steps**

Things I've done to verify, that all libraries are properly built with `-fPIC` and contain relocation info:

1. I unpacked all static libraries `ar -x <name>.a`
2. I ran `readelf --relocs <name>.cpp.o | egrep '(GOT|PC|PLT|JU?MP_SLOT)'` on each object-file to see if it contains relocation information.

Excerpt:

> 000000000036  217600000004 R_X86_64_PLT32    0000000000000000 _ZN9__gnu_cxx17__norma - 4
>   00000000004e  161000000004 R_X86_64_PLT32    0000000000000000 __stack_chk_fail - 4
>   000000000019  217700000004 R_X86_64_PLT32    0000000000000000 _ZNK9__gnu_cxx17__norm - 4
>   000000000028  217700000004 R_X86_64_PLT32    0000000000000000 _ZNK9__gnu_cxx17__norm - 4
>   000000000044  1ff700000004 R_X86_64_PLT32    0000000000000000 _ZNSt12_Vector_baseIN6 - 4
>   00000000005e  1ff800000004 R_X86_64_PLT32    0000000000000000 _ZSt8_DestroyIPN6engin - 4
>   000000000014  212f00000004 R_X86_64_PLT32    0000000000000000 _ZNKSt12__shared_ptrIN - 4
>   000000000014  217800000004 R_X86_64_PLT32    0000000000000000 _ZNSt13__future_base13 - 4
>   000000000020  213100000004 R_X86_64_PLT32    0000000000000000 _ZNKSt19__shared_ptr_a - 4
>   000000000014  212f00000004 R_X86_64_PLT32    0000000000000000 _ZNKSt12__shared_ptrIN - 4
>   000000000025  18b300000004 R_X86_64_PLT32    0000000000000000 _ZSt20__throw_future_e - 4
>   000000010248  089e00000002 R_X86_64_PC32     0000000000000000 .text._ZN9__gnu_cxxeqI + 0
>   000000010268  089f00000002 R_X86_64_PC32     0000000000000000 .text._ZNSt6vectorIN6e + 0
>   000000010271  007f00000002 R_X86_64_PC32     0000000000000000 .gcc_except_table + e68
>   00000001028c  08a000000002 R_X86_64_PC32     0000000000000000 .text._ZNKSt13packaged + 0
>   0000000102ac  08a100000002 R_X86_64_PC32     0000000000000000 .text.*ZNSt13packaged* + 0
>   0000000102cc  08a200000002 R_X86_64_PC32     0000000000000000 .text._ZN9__gnu_cxx17_ + 0
>   0000000102ec  08a300000002 R_X86_64_PC32     0000000000000000 .text._ZNK9__gnu_cxx17 + 0

3. I ran `readelf --debug-dump=macro <name>.o | grep __PIC__` to see, whether the `_PIC_` macro was defined and set to `2`, as described by the gcc compiler option reference.

Excerpt:

> DW_MACRO_define_strp - lineno : 0 macro : **PIC** 2

4. I crawled more 50 articles, stackoverflow entries and answers, all related to unresolved symbols related to functions/methods defined in the .cpp-files. In my case it's a symbol defined in a header-file, which is not found, which 
   is why I created another question.

---

**Result**

All tests verified successful `-fPIC` compilation and relocation symbol storage for each object file of the static libraries and shared libraries.

The only thing that didn't work:
The inclusion of the `enum class EEngineStatus` in the namespace `engine`, as reported by the linker error. The symbol `_ZN6enginelsERSoRKNS_13EEngineStatusE` is not contained in the affected `engine.cpp.o`.

---

**Suspected Influence**

I link one of the static libraries against the vulkan SDK, which is not `-fPIC` compiled as far as I know.

Could this break the entire linkage of a library unrelated to the vulkan SDK?

---

**Help**

Does anyone know, what I do wrong?

I sincerely hope, that anyone can help.
My knowledge is obviously too limited yet.

THank you in advance.

### Solution

Until @jww will write his answer, I'll provide it here for others to find.

It turns out that the header was processed, but I didn't understand the message.

Thanks to @jww I learned how to demangle the undefined symbol:

> echo _ZN6enginelsERSoRKNS_13EEngineStatusE | c++filt

This yielded the function not implemented, thus missing and I was able to fix the issues.

Comment: `echo _ZN6enginelsERSoRKNS_13EEngineStatusE | c++filt` results in `engine::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, engine::EEngineStatus const&)`. It looks like you need to either define or manually instantiate some of your functions.

Comment: @jww I will try it. Could you make an answer out of it for others to find it? Thanks for having had me learn something new with c++filt today!

Comment: @jww It worked. Thank you! Please write an answer so that I can credit you and the solution for other people.