# Why create shared library out of a set of static libaries in C?

Tags: c, static-linking, dynamic-linking, relocation

I'm currently working on an old program written in C that consists of a shared library and some utilities. The library is built by first building every subproject as a static c library and then linking those together in a shared library.

The layout of the project is very similar to the project in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52234570/linking-static-libraries-into-shared-enum-class-in-header-relocation-r-x86-6) question.

Previously I built my C programs by linking every object build together. What is the benefit of using static archives instead of object files in this case?

Comment: Are you sure you're not just looking at a limitation of an old compiler, or perhaps simply personal preference of the developer that wrote the library?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the benefit of using static archives instead of object files in this case?

There is no particular benefit, but building multiple archive libraries which are later linked into a single binary or shared library can make `Makefile`s easier to write. However, see "[Recursive Make Considered Harmful](https://web.archive.org/web/20070205211740/http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf)".